# cache problem uinsg php and jquery

Tags: php, jquery

i am using jquery stars plugin and asking users to rate . the form works well,but caching has become a big problem. even after refresh of the page .it does not show the latest ratings . only after i clear the cache new ratings gets showed.

Comment: I would recommend you to post relevant code that you are using. Current setup of your question can't really be answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be its due to issue in jquery cache

$.ajax({ url: "test.html", **cache: false**, success: function(html){ $("#results").append(html); } });

set cache to false will work fine.

Thanxs,
Gobi

Answer (score 0):

how are you getting the rating from the server? Try throw a random number or the current time in the get request.

Comment: its just the number value from the mysql table which i am fetching and displaying as stars.